# Javascript typeof operator on string-valued function returns "function" instead of "string"

Tags: javascript, typeof

```
var x=7;
console.log(typeof x);
// number
```

---

```
var x="7";
console.log(typeof x);
// string
```

---

```
var doh = "Doh";
console.log(typeof doh.toUpperCase);
// function
```

In the third example `.toUpperCase` returns a **string** and its `typeof` returns **function**?

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the result of `toUpperCase` is a String, but the `toUpperCase` itself is a function. You actually have to execute it, like this

```
console.log(typeof doh.toUpperCase());
// string
```

For example,

```
console.log(typeof 'thefourtheye'.toUpperCase);
// function
console.log('thefourtheye'.toUpperCase);
// [Function: toUpperCase]
console.log(typeof 'thefourtheye'.toUpperCase());
// string
console.log('thefourtheye'.toUpperCase());
// THEFOURTHEYE
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.toUpperCase()` The `toUpperCase()` method returns the calling string value converted to uppercase.

Whereas the `typeof` operator returns a string indicating the type of the operand, so `typeof doh.toUpperCase` is `function`.